Modifying GwcLayers through the official API failed with an error of 500. What is the reason?
This is the official API address for operating gwlayers: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/gwclayers.yaml
The GET and DELETE requests are normal, while the PUT and POST requests report a 500 error. My Geoserver version is 2.23.0. What is the reason for the error?
Here is my test:


GeoServer has logs. Looking at the logs (either on the command line, or using the web console) will probably provide something more meaningful, like a stack trace. Providing that might help.

Please don't post pictures of text, and don't bother blurring details out it isn't a secret
